# 2014 Passat sounds louder than before

Tags: noise, exhaust, passat, exhaust-manifold

I have a 2014 VW Passat 2.5L I bought it used last year. It was super quiet and great to drive when i bought it. It has close to 80000 km on it. The past few months I had i sitting in the garage not used. To be precise 8 months in the garage, out of which took it out for spin may be 3 times during that period. car was sitting with small amount of gas in the tank. couple of weeks ago i started using the car again for daily use. But now it sounds way louder than before.

I am wondering what might have happened in the past 8 months of idle time. I filled up the tank as well. i am planning to take to mechanic this week but due to covid situation i am worried to let others touch insides of the car and then i use it so was wondering if i could check things out myself. Any suggestions what could cause louder engine after a few months of idle sitting in garage?

Answer (score -2):

You will have to go through your exhaust system for a moment .and i would advise draining the the gas that was already in the tank as you suggested the car had been stationary for a moment .the gas must have deteriorated over the Time and its now more like thinus so if u are going to syphon it beware of choking yourself .

Comment: Are you advising draining the fresh fuel that has just been put in? If so, why?

Comment: Actually i was suggesting that you empty up the tank and even clean it before you pour in some fresh Gas .

Comment: Can you explain why you would do that? For such a short period of time, I can see no benefit. And in any case, the exhaust system is absolutely where I'd start looking.

Comment: Thanks I will find a way to empty the tank and clean it.